# C# asynch SQL inside singleton and delegates

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to build a class that will be responsible for all operations on database.

Using singleton pattern from here: http://codebender.denniland.com/a-singleton-base-class-to-implement-the-singleton-pattern-in-c/

I've build a class like so:

```
class DB : SingletonBase<DB>
    {

        public static readonly string SqlConnectionString  = @"Data Source=MYDB;Initial Catalog=PRODUCTS;Integrated Security=True;Asynchronous Processing=true;";

        private DB()
        {
        }

        public void loadData()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "STATISTICS_1";

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback), cmd, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }

        private void HandleCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            SqlDataReader dr;
            SqlCommand _this = (SqlCommand)result.AsyncState;

            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                dr = _this.EndExecuteReader(result);
            }
            else
                dr = null;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            dr.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("loaded");
        }
    }
```

In my main class I'm using this like so:

```
    private void loadStatistics(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showStatus("loading data");
        DB.Instance.loadData();
    }
```

But this will give me only my message box.

What I would like to do is to declare function in my main class that will be called after SQL query return something.

I think that the best way would by using events, but I don't know how to do that proper way.

I would like to do something like this in my main class:

```
    private void loadCompleted(string msg)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }

    private void loadStatistics(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showStatus("loading data");
        DB.Instance.loadData(loadCompleted);
    }
```

So that I can specify function that will be called after SQL call is finished.

I don't know if this is the best way of doing this, so any comments, suggestions and solutions are welcome.

**What I would like to achieve is to have one class responsible for calling SQL asynchronously and passing data to other functions that will process it.**

Comment: Have you taken a look at delegates?

Comment: Bytheway: singletons are evil: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil

Comment: Yes I know that I could use delegates, but I had problems when I've tried that. Also I would like to know is my idea good. Should I use singleton and how to call method from it. When I call `BeginExecuteReader` I must pass somehow name of function that must be called after sql is executed. Idea behind that is to be able to call 10 queries to sql server so they all will execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public delegate void NotifyCallback(string message);    

public class ClassWithCommandAndCallback 
{
  public SqlCommand Sql;
  public NotifyCallback Callback;
}

public void loadData(NotifyCallback callback)
{
  ClassWithCommandAndCallback ar = new ClassWithCommandAndCallback();
  ar.Sql = cmd;
  ar.Callback = callback;
  IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteReader(new AsyncCallback(HandleCallback), ar, CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}

private void HandleCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
  ClassWithCommandAndCallback ar = (ClassWithCommandAndCallback)result.AsyncState;

  ar.Callback("loaded (SQL was: "+ar.Sql+")");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :) But how to pass `callback` to my `HandleCallback` function. Function that is visible in my singleton is loadData, it start my sql query, after query is completed `HandleCallback` is called, there I check if my query executed successful. If NO I want to show error message, if Yes then call my function from my main class. I know this might sound silly, but I don't know how to pass callback function to `HandleCallback`. Sorry for troubles :)

Comment: Instead of `cmd` use a class as parameter for `BeginExecuteReader` which contains the SqlCommand AND the callback. Then you will have both available in your HandleCallback method.

Comment: Could You please show me how to modify my 2 functions `loadData` and `HandleCallback` to accomplish this?

Comment: Look at my edit. Is it clear from that? You can give one parameter into the HandleCallback which is IAsyncResult.AsyncState. Instead to give only the SqlCommand give a more complex object into it which holds both, the command and the callback.

Comment: It's getting clearer :) One more thing, how to declare `ClassWithCommandAndCallback`? Would it be better to have 2 callbacks? One that will process data when sql completed without errors and second that will get called when any error occurs?

Comment: You can add as many callbacks as you want. I would recommend to add another parameter to the notify which tells what the result was. As enum for example. Then you can tell the caller that the command failed or executed successful. Thats up to you.

Comment: BTW is mine solution fine? So I should add parameter to `NotifyCallback` delegate and to my function that will be called when I get result from sql server. I think better will be to add second callback, one will handle success and second any errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16652/discussion-between-bluem-and-misiu)