# SQL Query Result to List<T> mapping

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

In my database I have 2 tables:

```
id   | name |  city  | street
-------------------------------
   1 | John | London | Street1
   2 | Will | London | Street1
   3 | Adam | LA     | Street1

id   | uid | phone
------------------
   1 |    1| 12345
   2 |    1| 23456
   3 |    2| 16505
   4 |    3| 65909
   5 |    3| 68902
   6 |    3| 15905
```

I need to select that data and store into List (or Dictionary as user Id is unique)

My uses class looks like so:

```
public class User
{
    //lock
    private static readonly object userLock = new object();

    public int      Id        { get; set; }
    public string   Name      { get; set; }
    public string   City      { get; set; }
    public string   Street    { get; set; }

    public List<string> Phones { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {
        Phones = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddPhone(string phone)
    {
        lock (userLock)
        {
            Phones.Add(phone);
        }
    }
}
```

Idea is to load those users info into application, add/remove/modify phones and save those changed/removed/added.

I found idea for solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11687743/965722, but I imagine this as doing one query to get users list and then for each user I need separate query to get his phones.

How should I do my loading?
Can I do it with only one query?
How should I populate my result collection?
Should I use List or Dictionary? Then I could remove `Id` from User class and have it as key inside dictionary.

I'm using .NET 3.5 and would like to avoid Entity Framework or ORM's.

Comment: Just curious, why you want to avoid EF or ORM which is the best suit for your case?

Comment: What is your existing mechanism for accessing the database?

Comment: @Cuong Le - I'm building my application modular and idea is that every user will be able to add his own functionality. If I use EF then everyone will be obligated to use it (I may be wrong at this one :P)

Comment: @Jon - I'm using mostly MSSQL server and stored procedures and from C# I call them asynchronous as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408835/c-sharp-asynch-sql-inside-singleton-and-delegates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a class Phone and change the User property accordingly:

```
public class Phone
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    // (etc)
    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    // (etc)        
}
```

Make a PhoneRepository:

```
public class PhoneRepository
{
    public List<Phone> LoadPhonesFromId(IEnumerable<int> ids)
    {
       // write a query with the ids
       // SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2, ...)
       // execute the query
       // convert the results to Phones and put them in a List<Phone>
       // return the list
    }
    public List<Phone> LoadPhonesFromUserId(IEnumerable<int> userIds)
    {
       // write a query with the userIds
       // SELECT * FROM Phones WHERE userId IN (@userId1, @userId2, ...)
       // execute the query
       // convert the results to Phones and put them in a List<Phone>
       // return the list
    }
}
```

And a UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository
{
    public List<User> LoadUsersFromUserIds(IEnumerable<int> userIds)
    {
       // write a query with the userIds
       // SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (@id1, @id2, ...)
       // execute the query
       // convert the results to Users and put them in a List<User>
       // return the list
    }

    public void IncludePhones(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {            
        var phones = PhoneRepository.LoadPhonesFromUserId
            (users.Select(x => x.Id));

        for each(var user in users)
        {
            user.Phones = phones
                .Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

You can greatly expand and improve on this pattern with, for example, custom filter parameters (instead of different functions for the various filters) and property setters that make sure the user and user.Phones keep referring to the same userID, but that is sort of beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: thanks for Your suggestion, this is almost the same code as I have right now, except that I have all inside one method. This works fine, but as I wrote I would like to avoid multiple queries, but as I see this is almost impossible, especially user may not have any phones at beginning.

Comment: sorry for my silly comment :) I can do load with just 2 queries instead of n. For now I'll stay with this solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to .net 4, then take a look at [ObjectContext.Translate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx) - you can use this without a "real" entity model, an empty unsubclassed objectcontext suffices and will map objects even if they're not entities.  This solution has no third party dependencies, but it's a little slower and less flexible than the open source libraries available.

If .net 4.0 is not an option or you want more features and performance you may want to look at a third-party lib:

- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) Unwraps plain POCOs nicely and has nice parametrized queries.  Also very fast.  The newest version is .net 4.0, but there's a 3.5 version too.
- [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) Another simple POCO unwrapper, .net 3.5
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) I don't know much about this one.

Each project also lists a few other competitors; I'm sure you can find an appropriate choice amongst them that allows you to write plain sql with easily parametrized queries and have results be automatically unwrapped into plain objects.  The performance overhead is virtually nil; so this solution is (IMHO) always preferable to raw data readers; it's so much easier in daily use.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this requires .NET4 (from what I see in MSDN) and as I wrote in my question I'm limited to .NET 3.5

Comment: That's unfortunate - it's certainly an easy solution.  I'll add a few similar variants to the answer.

Comment: Do these other libraries help?

Comment: I don't know them (not yet :) ) PetaPoco looks grate, I can add one cs file to my project and it will work :) Could You help me with my case using PetaPoco?

Comment: The documentation should suffice - it's really simple.  BTW, your usage of manual locking looks dangerous: you're locking writes but not reads, which can lead to undefined behavior (I'd recommend avoiding multithreaded read/write access to objects with very few exceptions).

Comment: I'm loading data in one thread, then I start multiple treads, one for one service - each one is searching for additional numbers using webservices (WCF and REST), they are adding data using lock, and after loading and manual edits I'm again using one thread saving changes to db. How do You suggest I should change my User class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23661/discussion-between-eamon-nerbonne-and-misiu)

Comment: @Misiu: did you end up making a choice?